# Regex validation fails on sonarqube

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have the following regex validation for special characters:

```
.match(/[`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-=_\\\[\]{}/\?,\.\<\>]/)
```

It works, but it doesn't pass on sonarqube, I get a security hotspot error:

"Evaluating regular expressions against input strings is potentially an extremely CPU-intensive task. Specially crafted regular expressions such as (a+)+s will take several seconds to evaluate the input string.

The problem is that with every additional a character added to the input, the time required to evaluate the regex doubles. However, the equivalent regular expression, a+s (without grouping) is efficiently evaluated in milliseconds and scales linearly with the input size."

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: do you want to eliminate all special characters? why not using `\W` ?
`

Comment: hmm perhaps I can limit only # / \ , these ones were making me troubles.. I don't understand /W ?

Comment: `W` match all non-digits and non literals characters, so all special characters

Comment: I tried /W now and doesn't apply on # / \ characters

Comment: You don't need to mask (precede it with "\") all your characters within a`[]` character class definition. Maybe you will get better results by not masking `(` and `)`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, how the regex should look like?

Comment: Are you sure? i'm quite sure of the contrary: https://regex101.com/r/tMlQby/2

Answer (score 0):

To answer @Greedo: "Yes, I am sure." In character classes only the closing square bracket and the backslash need to be masked if you put the "-" at the end of the character list. The following works, but I don't know how Sonarqube will respond.

```js
let res="[`~!@#$%^&*)(=_\\[]{}/?,.<>-]".match(/[`~!@#$%^&*)(=_\\[\]{}/?,.<>-]/g);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: still doesn't pass sonarqube, but I've managed to have a solution. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: For what it is worth: the Sonarqube message refers to grouping within RegExp patterns. There is no grouping here and the message most likely shows up because the Sonarqube parser misinterpreted the parentheses contained in the character list.

Comment: I think you're right, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution, limited the regex validation to certain characters, like #, /, \ and now it's ok.